# Error using irb() interface - HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected rescue in block in parse header

Tags: android, ruby, calabash

I'm new on Ruby/Calabash language  and I'm doing some example  using irb(main) interface; I Have installed myFirstApp on android emulator using 'reinstall_apps' and  when I digit query("*") command in irb() interface I get this error :

```
HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclie
nt/session.rb:887:in `rescue in block in parse_header
```

Could you help me please..

Answer (score 5):

After `reinstall_apps` command you need to run `start_test_server_in_background`.

It will start the test server and the app. Now you can run `query("*")` command in irb(main) console.